# Como salvar imagem blob com multer no nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, multer, longblob

Bem eu tenho essa tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho esse código que recebo uma imagem pelo multer no nodejs:

```js
routes.post('/salvarImagem', upload.single('Img') , (req, res) => {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        port     : 3306,
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'jubart'
    });

    var query = "INSERT INTO tb_imagens (FK_Portifolio, Imagem, Nome, Tipo, Tamanho) VALUES (" + req.body.Portifolio + ", BINARY(" + req.file.buffer.toString('binary') + "), '" + req.file.originalname + "', '" + req.file.mimetype + "', '" + req.file.size + "')";

    connection.query(query, function(error, results, fields){
        if(error) 
            res.json(error);
        else{
            res.json(results);
        }
        connection.end();
    });
});
```

Ele salva mas a imagem ele salva errado ele não salva como arquivo binário mas sim um arquivo com a base64 escrita e quando eu retorno do banco não consigo exibir a imagem. Alguém sabe como eu converto o req.file.buffer para o formato blob para eu salvar?

Comment: Já tentou substituir `BINARY(" + req.file.buffer.toString('binary') + ")` por `" + req.file.buffer + ")`?

Comment: Sim e assim n salva